# Custom trigger for a Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to monitor a remote SFTP folder in order to trigger my Jenkins scripted pipeline.

I have searched on Google and Jenkins documentation but i cannot found where to insert the custom code that will be used by Jenkins to decide to trigger or not my job.

Do you know if it's possible or should i wrote a custom plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that push triggering of builds isn't possible and you need to fall back to polling.

In this situation I would create a **second** *pipeline job* which monitors the remote SFTP folder. If a change is detected it will then trigger the actual job using the `build` step. Something in the lines of:

```
node {
  def changes = false;
  // Do your monitoring of the SFTP server here and set changes to true if changes are detected. If you need a state between different runs of this job, then you can use the archive and copyArtifact step to save and retrieve state from last run.
  if (changes) {
    build job: 'A', propagate: false, wait: false
  }
```

You then set this *job* to be **triggered periodically**:

[image: Triggering periodically]